# sim808 freezes after one SMS using stm32

Tags: arm, stm32

I am trying to design a GPS car tracker with a SIM808 module using a STM32F103RET6 header board and I want to get the location link messaged to my phone by sending an SMS to the module. Right now my code works but only when I reset the board after sending each SMS. I attached my code can you figure out what is the problem?

main code :

```
#include <stm32f10x.h>
#include "usart.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

char S=0x1A;
#define Enter    usart_sendchar('\n');
#define CR       usart_sendchar('\r');
#define GIM      usart_sendchar('"');
#define SUB      usart_sendchar(S);
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include <string.h>
char get_Enter = 0;
uint8_t ch;
 char str1[300];
char str2[100];
int i=0;
char flag=0;
char str_tmp[20];
char str_tmp2[20];
char* p;


volatile uint32_t msTicks;

//calling all the functions 

void Send_SMS(char *text);
void CMTI(void);
void wait_to_get(char ch);
void del_All_SMS(void);
void CMGF_1(void);
void Delay (uint32_t Time);
void CMGR (void);
void CGNSPWR_1(void);
void CGNSINF(void);
void interrupt_activation(void);
void CGNSINF_C(void);
void AT(void);
void Delay (uint32_t dlyTicks);
void SysTick_Handler(void);


// the interrupt handler for the systick module 
void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    msTicks++;
}
void Delay (uint32_t dlyTicks) {
    uint32_t curTicks;
    curTicks = msTicks;
    while ((msTicks - curTicks)< dlyTicks);
}








void Send_SMS(char *text)
{
CMGF_1(); 
Delay(500);       
str_tmp[0]='\0';
Delay(100);       

strcpy(str_tmp,"AT+CMGS=");
Delay(500);       
usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
GIM
str_tmp[0]='\0';
Delay(100);       

strcpy(str_tmp,"+98905xxxxxxx");
Delay(500);       
usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
GIM
Enter
CR

Delay(500);           

 usart_sendstring(text);
Enter
CR
str_tmp[0]='\0';
Delay(500);       
SUB

Delay(100);
del_All_SMS();
}
void USART1_IRQHandler(void) {

        ch = USART1->DR & 0xFF; 
    if (ch == '\n'){ // 13 enter
             
                  get_Enter =1;
        
         }
        else{
            str1[i]= ch;
            i++;
        }
 }


            
             
             
             
             
             
                 



    
    void CMGF_1(void)
 {
    str_tmp[0]='\0';
    Delay(100);       
    strcpy(str_tmp,"AT+CMGF=1");
    Delay(500);       
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
  Enter
    CR  
    
 }


 void del_All_SMS(void)
 {
str_tmp[0]='\0';
Delay(100);
strcpy(str_tmp,"AT+CMGD=1,4");
Delay(500);       
usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
Enter
CR   
}
 
 
    void CMGR(void)
 {
    str_tmp[0]='\0';
  
    Delay(100);      
    strcpy(str_tmp,"AT+CMGR=1");
  Delay(500);    
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
  Enter
    CR  
    
 }
    void CGNSINF(void)
 {
    str_tmp[0]='\0';
    Delay(100);       
    strcpy(str_tmp,"AT+CGNSINF");
    Delay(500);       
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
  Enter
    CR      
    
 }
void CGNSPWR_1(void)
 {
    str_tmp[0]='\0';
    Delay(100);       
    strcpy(str_tmp,"AT+CGNSPWR=1");
        Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR  
    
 }
 
 void AT(void)
 {
    str_tmp[0]='\0';  
    Delay(100);  
    strcpy(str_tmp,"AT");
        Delay(500);
    usart_sendstring(str_tmp);
    Enter
    CR  
    
 }
 
 
 
 
 
 
    
    
int main() 
    {
    SystemInit();
  SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock/1000); // setup systick timer for 1ms interrupts
    usart_init();   
        
  AT();
        
        p=NULL;
         
            check:AT();
  
        Delay(2000);
        
        p=strstr(str1,"OK");   
        if(p==NULL) goto check;
        
             
  CMGF_1();
    Delay(500);

    CGNSPWR_1();
    
    Delay(500); 
  del_All_SMS();
    
    Delay(500);
        
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<3); 
    GPIOB->CRL &= ~0xF;
  GPIOB->CRL |= 0x3;    
    
        
while (1)
{
    
    if (get_Enter ==1)
    {
      if (flag==0){
       ////waiting for +CMTI: from sim800
            do
     {  
      p=strstr(str1,"+CMTI:");   
      } 
         while(p==NULL);
      Delay(1000);
                // sending AT+CMGR=1 command
            if (p!=NULL)
            {
                    CMGR();
            
                    Delay(350);
                flag=1;
            }
        }
    if (flag==1) {
        p=strstr(str1,"+CMGR");
            if (p){
                p=strstr(str1,"loc");
                                
if (p!=NULL)
{

CGNSINF();
    Delay(300);
}
else if (p==NULL)
{
del_All_SMS();
memset(str1, 0, 300);   
    flag=0;
    
}
p=strstr(str1,"+CGNSINF:");
if (p)
{


float a[5];
          
char str2[80];
   const char s[2] = ",";
   char *token;
   // getting the lattitude and longitude 
   token = strtok(p, s);
   
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
      sprintf( str2," %s\n", token );
        a[i]=atof(str2);
    
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
    } 

sprintf(str2,"https://maps.google.com/?q=%.6f,%.6f",a[3],a[4]);
Send_SMS(str2);
p=NULL; 
del_All_SMS();
    flag=0;
memset(str1, 0, 300);




    } 



      } 
            
            
        } 
        }  
             
             
        } 
            
        
    }
```

usart code :

```
    #include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "usart.h"
    char str[200];
    char data;

//// initialize usart
void usart_init(void) 
 {

  RCC->APB2ENR |=  (   1UL <<  0);        /* enable clock Alternate Function  */
  AFIO->MAPR   &= ~(   1UL <<  2);        /* clear USART1 remap               */

  RCC->APB2ENR |=  (   1UL <<  2);        /* enable GPIOA clock               */
  GPIOA->CRH   &= ~(0xFFUL <<  4);        /* clear PA9, PA10                  */
  GPIOA->CRH   |=  (0x0BUL <<  4);        /* USART1 Tx (PA9) output push-pull */
  GPIOA->CRH   |=  (0x04UL <<  8);        /* USART1 Rx (PA10) input floating  */

  RCC->APB2ENR |=  (   1UL << 14);        /* enable USART#1 clock             */
  USART1->BRR=0x1D4C;   // 9600 @72MHz
//  USART1->BRR   = 0x0271;                 /* 115200 baud @ PCLK2 72MHz        */
  USART1->CR1   = ((   1UL <<  2) |       /* enable RX                        */
                   (   1UL <<  3) |       /* enable TX                        */
                   (   0UL << 12) );      /* 1 start bit, 8 data bits         */
  USART1->CR2   = 0x0000;                 /* 1 stop bit                       */
  USART1->CR3   = 0x0000;                 /* no flow control                  */

  USART1->CR1  |= ( 1 << 13);      /* enable USART                     */
    
    USART1->CR1  |= ( 1UL << 5);     // RXNE interrupt enable
    NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn,5); /* Default priority group 0, can be 0(highest) - 31(lowest) */
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);     /* Enable UART0 Interrupt */
}





void usart_sendchar(char data){
    while(!(USART1->SR&(1<<7)));
    USART1->DR=data;
}
char usart_getchar(void) 
    {
        
    while (!(USART1->SR&(1<<5)));
    data=USART1->DR ;
  return data;      
    }


void usart_getstring(char *str) 
{

  char *temp = str;
    
    do{
        
        *temp = usart_getchar();
        usart_sendchar (*temp) ;
        
    } while(*(temp++) != 0x0D );
    *(temp-1) = 0;

}

void usart_sendstring(char *s) 
{
    while (*s) 
    {
    usart_sendchar(*s);
        s++;
    }
}
```